# Why must $x$ be not free in $\psi$ in order for $(\psi\to\phi)\vDash[\psi\to(\forall x\phi)]$?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, quantifiers, formal-systems

In the PDF textbook ["A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic 2nd Edition" by Christopher C. Leary and Lars Kristiansen](https://minerva.geneseo.edu/a-friendly-introduction-to-mathematical-logic/), page 53, the first quantifier inference rule (QR) is defined by the ordered pair $(\Gamma,\theta)$ such that $\Gamma=\{\psi\to\phi\}$ and $\theta=\psi\to(\forall x\phi)$ where $x$ is not free in the formula $\psi$ **(note this is important)**. The book provides a proof of $\Gamma\vDash\theta$ on page 56, but I decided to give my own, very similar proof.

My proof goes as follows:

$$\Gamma\vDash\theta\iff(\psi\to\phi)\vDash[\psi\to(\forall x\phi)]$$

Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be some fixed, arbitrary interpretation. Thus, continuing forth,

$$(\psi\to\phi)\vDash[\psi\to(\forall x\phi)]\iff\mathfrak{U}\vDash(\psi\to\phi)\Rightarrow\mathfrak{U}\vDash[\psi\to(\forall x\phi)]$$

If $\mathfrak{U}\not\vDash(\psi\to\phi),$ then we're done, so let's assume $\mathfrak{U}\vDash(\psi\to\phi)$ which we'll donote **(Assumption 1)**. This leaves us to prove $\mathfrak{U}\vDash[\psi\to(\forall x\phi)]$ under **(Assumption 1)**.

$$\mathfrak{U}\vDash[\psi\to(\forall x\phi)]\iff\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi\Rightarrow\mathfrak{U}\vDash(\forall x\phi)$$

Like previously, if $\mathfrak{U}\not\vDash\psi$, then we're done, so let's assume $\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi$ which we'll denote **(Assumption 2)**. This leaves us to prove $\mathfrak{U}\vDash(\forall x\phi)$ under **(Assumption 2)**.

\begin{align}
  \mathfrak{U}\vDash(\forall x\phi)&\iff(\forall s)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash(\forall x\phi)[s]) \\
                                   &\iff(\forall s)(\forall a)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\phi[s[x|a]]) \\
  \text{Let $s=t$ be some fixed, arbitrary} \\ \text{variable assignment function into $\mathfrak{U}$.} \\
                                   &\iff(\forall a)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\phi[t[x|a]]) &&(1)
\end{align}

From **(Assumption 1)**,

\begin{align}
  \mathfrak{U}\vDash(\psi\to\phi)&\iff\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi\Rightarrow\mathfrak{U}\vDash\phi \\
                                 &\iff(\forall s)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi[s])\Rightarrow(\forall s)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\phi[s]) \\
  \text{Let $s=t[x|a]$ be the same x-modified} \\ 
  \text{assignment function seen in (1).} \\
&\iff\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi[t[x|a]]\Rightarrow\mathfrak{U}\vDash\phi[t[x|a]]) \\
                                 &\iff(\forall a)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi[t[x|a]])\Rightarrow(\forall a)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\phi[t[x|a]]) && (2)
\end{align}

From **(Assumption 2)**,

\begin{align}
  \mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi&\iff(\forall s)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi[s]) \\
  \text{Let $s=t[x|a]$ be the same x-modified} \\ 
  \text{assignment function seen in (1).} \\
                        &\iff\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi[t[x|a]] \\
                        &\iff(\forall a)(\mathfrak{U}\vDash\psi[t[x|a]])&&(3)
\end{align}

Frome (2) and (3), we can deduce (1) and thus we have proven $\mathfrak{U}\vDash(\forall x\phi)$ and we are done. (I have left out some of the final steps, but the remaining steps should be trivial to complete from here hopefully.) $\square$

I'm pretty sure this proof is correct, but the only thing I'm unsure about is the necessity that $x$ be not free in $\psi$. The proof shown in the book uses this fact to help prove $\Gamma\vDash\theta$, so it makes me uneasy about the validity of my proof. From my proof, it seems unnecessary that $x$ be not free in the $\psi$, but I'm might be missing something. Can someone show me where I'm mistaken within my proof and explain why $x$ must not be free in $\psi$.

Comment: The reason that we need $x$ to not be free is that $x$ could be mentioned in $\psi$ and $\phi$, but we are only adding a quantifier to $\phi$. For example $x = y \to x =y$ but $x = y \not \to (\forall x)[x = y]$.

Comment: The error is in the equivalence following : "This leaves us to prove $\mathfrak U \vDash [ψ→(∀xϕ)]$ under (Assumption 1)." See page 38, Ex.1.9.1.4 : $\vDash (\phi \to \psi)$ and $\phi \vDash \psi$ are **not** equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

> Why must $x$ be not free in $ψ$ in order for $(ψ→ϕ) ⊨ [ψ→(∀xϕ)]$ ?

Because with $x$ free the inference is not *valid*.

In order to see why the condition is necessary, we can consider the following counter-example : $\psi,\phi := (x=0)$ and consider the stucture $\mathbb N$.

We want to show that :

> $(x=0) \to (x=0) \vDash (x=0) \to \forall x (x=0).$

This means [see page 36] :

> > if $\mathbb N \vDash ((x=0) \to (x=0))$, then $\mathbb N \vDash (x=0) \to \forall x (x=0))$.

See page 37 :

> This definition is a little bit tricky. It says that if $\Delta$ is true in $\mathfrak A$, then $\Delta$ is true in $\mathfrak A$. Remember, for $\Delta$ to be true in $\mathfrak A$, it must be the case that $\mathfrak A \vDash \Delta[s]$ for *every* assignment function $s$.

Now we cam follow your proof considering $\mathbb N$ as $\mathfrak U$.

> let's assume **(1)** : $\mathbb N \vDash ((x=0) → (x=0))$;

this assumption is clearly correct.

And we have to show that $(x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$ is true in $\mathbb N$, i.e. that :

> $\mathbb N \vDash (x=0) \to \forall x (x=0))[s]$, for every assignment function $s$.

If $s(x) \ne 0$, we are done (the antecedent is False).

The issue is when $s(x)=0$, because we want that : $\mathbb N \vDash (\forall x(x=0))[s]$.

In order to have this, we need that :

> > $\mathbb N \vDash (x=0)[t[x|n]]$, for every $n \in \mathbb N$,
>
> where $t[x|n]$ is an "$x$-variant" of $s$, i.e. is as $s$ except for $s(x)=n$.

*And here we are stuck*....

Clearly :

> > $\mathbb N \nvDash (x=0)[t[x|1]]$.

Comment: I still need help finding at which step my proof fails and why it failed. I understand your counter-example, but I'm having a hard time using it to backtrack through my proof and locate the exact error I made.